# Given that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x = 0$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Is this the same as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}=-\frac{1}{2}. $

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x = 0$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Is this the same as
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} =-\frac {1}{2}.
$$

Comment: $f'(a)=-\frac12\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=-\frac12$.

Comment: If $a=0$ then yes.

Comment: Would this further simplify into lim→0 f(x)/ x = -1/2.

Comment: No, it simplifies into $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(0))/x=-\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to go back to your textbook and check the definition of derivative of $f(x)$ at $x = a$

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$$

So, if you need $f'(0)$, then you need to compute

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

rather than

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

for some arbitrary $a$.